# C# gRPC example without proto buffers?

Tags: c#, grpc

I've been searching around and have not been able to find any concrete **EXAMPLES** using gRPC without proto buffers **in C#**. I've found the "gRPC + JSON" blog post but that is for Java and not easily applicable to c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose the natural question here is - why do you want to use gRPC without proto buffers?

Comment: A more senior developer does not like proto buffers and insists that we not use them, so I'm trying to see if there is a way with gRPC.

Comment: gRPC C# can be used with other serialization formats (e.g. Flatbuffers or MS Bond), but we don't provide official examples because we recommend using gRPC C# with protocolbuffers (that will give you the best developer experience and support). Some random examples I found: https://github.com/microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/grpc/pingpong

Comment: A small example of a services that only uses raw payloads (not protobufs) is directly in the gRPC codebase: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/af1eaa0d058cdd319a975c2afeaf6383bdec2753/src/csharp/Grpc.IntegrationTesting/GenericService.cs#L50

Answer (score -1):

Was looking for the same thing and found [**MagicOnion**](https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion) (injected as service into existing ASP.NET app)

from `README.md`:

> This framework is based on gRPC, which is a fast and compact binary
> network transport for HTTP/2. However, unlike plain gRPC, it treats C#
> interfaces as a protocol schema, enabling seamless code sharing
> between C# projects **without .proto** (Protocol Buffers IDL).

Answer (score -1):

MagicOnion already mentioned, and here are  some other rpc projects that use grpc without protobuf:

https://github.com/netcore-jroger/SimpleRpc

https://github.com/max-ieremenko/ServiceModel.Grpc

https://github.com/osexpert/GoreRemoting

Disclaimer: the last one belongs to me